# EC2 Boot Partition

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to boot a custom Fedora 12-based OS on Amazon EC2 and am having struggles. The boot partition is on /dev/md0p1, which I have specified with "--root-device-name /dev/md0p1" when registering my image bundle. However, I get this error when I try to run it:

```
XENBUS: Timeout connecting to devices!
md: Autodetecting RAID arrays.
md: autorun ...
md: ... autorun DONE.
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(8,1)
```

(8, 1) is /dev/sda1 on my disk. What else do I need to do to specify the partition? Here is my /boot/grub/grub.conf file on the VMDK image I used in the bundle:

```
default=0
timeout=5

# make it purty
splashimage /splash.xpm.gz
background 4040ff
foreground ffe4b5

title tty
root (hd0, 0)
kernel /vmlinuz-p1 ro rootpart=1 stable=1 updgen=0 mm_uuid=<long uuid> dev_uuid=<long, different uuid> quiet
initrd /initrd-p1
```

Thanks in advance! :)

EDIT: Thanks for the reply, Rico. Here are the commands I used:

```
ec2-bundle-image -i system.vmdk -r x86_64 -c <certificate> -k <key> --user <user id>

ec2-upload-bundle -b <bucket name> -m /tmp/system.vmdk.manifest.xml -a <access id> -s <secret access id>

ec2-register <bucket name>/system.vmdk.manifest.xml --root-device-name /dev/md0p1

ec2-run-instances <the AMI ID>
```

Also tried registering one with the following but it terminated before even getting console output:

```
ec2-register <bucket name>/system.vmdk.manifest.xml --root-device-name /dev/md0p1 --virtualization-type hvm
```

Comment: Can you post the full command that you are using to register your AMI ?

Answer (score 1):

grub.conf is ignored by AWS instances. Basically AWS uses its own methods on how to boot an instance.  You generally need to specify something like:

```
--root-device-name /dev/sda1
```

when you register the instance.